# How to display multiple rows from a table without using cursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an existing table. I have a select query which might return multiple rows. I want to display all rows that this select query returns, **without using cursor**. How can I achieve it *in pl sql*?

Comment: Why in PL/SQL? Display to who, and how? Why can't you use a (visible) cursor, and what other mechanism are you envisaging - a PL/SQL loop somehow selecting a single row each time around!? Do maybe mean not an explicit cursor, and an implicit one would be OK?

Comment: I have learnt from google that this can be easily done using explicit cursor, but my course that I am pursuing doesn't have the concept of cursor.

Comment: You may need to explain your restrictions. What exactly have you been told you can't do? Specify a cursor in the `declare` section, or any kind of cursor, including implicit and ref cursors? What about bulk collect - are PL/SQL collections OK? And you haven't said how/where you want to display the results.

Comment: I am just a student. We use oracle 10g express edition. We need to display output in the result area. My concern was just to know is there any option other than using explicit cursor to display multiple rows that select query might return?

Comment: Guys, I have already accepted answer of Randoll Revers. I don't find any reason for still being unclear of the question as there's someone at the other end of the world who has understood what I was asking for and there's someone who has already answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the following is a possible solution:

```
BEGIN
    FOR T IN (SELECT 'data_1' col_1, 
                     'data_2' col_2, 
                     'data_3' col_3
              FROM   dual) LOOP

    dbms_output.put_line('Query returns: '||T.col_1||', '||T.col_2||', '||T.col_3);

    END LOOP;
END;
```